# Need help deleting a question

Tags: support, deleting

I wanted to delete a [question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/82199/32436), couldn't, and flagged it for deletion (as suggested by the software.  But the flag was declined.

I copied the  crux of Jake's answer over to my new question, so it is no longer necessary to keep the original answer open.

It took me a little while to think of this solution, and in the meantime, multiple answers of a poorly posed question were received, and one received 6 votes.  Thus I can't delete the question.

Comment: Related - http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/283118/193412

Answer (score 3):

As per the [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221/254250):

> ## If I flag my question with a request to delete it, what will happen?
>
> The standard policy for moderators is to decline such flags. The reasoning is as follows:
>
> - if you can delete your question (because it has no answers, or the only answer has no upvotes), then you should do it. It does not require moderator intervention.
> - if you cannot delete your question, then there must be upvoted, or multiple answers. Deleting the question also deletes the answers. Deleting the answers undoes the hard work other people have put in to answer your question, and reverses the reputation they have earned too. This is not fair to the answerers of your question.

Adding the content of the answer to another question, then deleting the original, is not really a solution. First, the author of the answer deserves to have it listed in his account, and to continue accruing reputation points as people vote in it. (Not that jakebeal is in great need of points... but it's nice for both the author of an answer, and future readers, to see how many others have found it useful so far.)  Second, it makes the Q&A harder to find, for people who are searching for that question. We are trying to build a library of useful questions and answers for future readers (and many people, myself included, contribute answers with the goal of helping future readers and not only the person asking the question). It's not as easy to find an answer if it's not attached to a question that it answers.

Instead, consider editing your question to improve it. For example, I think the following version of your question would be much better received, and wouldn't invalidate the excellent answer that you received:

> ## Why does an admissions committee need to look at the whole transcript?
>
> Admissions committees look at a student's entire transcript to get an understanding of their academic abilities. Why is it not sufficient to judge a student's academics based on GPA alone?

(and remove the [reference-request](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference-request) tag)

Comment: "We are trying to build a library of useful questions and answers for future readers" - but with a score of negative 5, my question doesn't appear to have been considered remotely useful.  Also, I don't think Jake's answer will accrue more points.  (Note that Jake did a great job of restating my question, but he didn't answer it.)  // All that said, I'm fine with following your suggestion (even though it's not remotely what I was thinking about when I wrote the question).

Comment: I forgot to say, I don't need the reference any more.  I found a different way of presenting my argument.